# Jhipster application hangs on Pivotal Cloud Foundry after printing banner

Tags: jhipster, cloud-foundry

I've created a JHipster application using the following

```
yo jhipster
yo jhipster:cloudfoundry
```

However, when I push to PCF, the app starts, hangs after printing the banner and gets killed after a minute.

The only customization I've tried is changing the URLs in some properties to point to a JHipster registry deployed on cloudfoundry as described in [the jhipster documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/#cloudfoundry).

This is my .yo-rc.json file:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.3.0",
    "baseName": "test",
    "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
    "packageFolder": "com/mycompany/myapp",
    "serverPort": "8081",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "eureka",
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "bec0ab8352f04338c8c1db2fd572022c1bf877fe",
    "enableTranslation": false,
    "applicationType": "microservice",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "skipClient": true,
    "skipUserManagement": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the app working locally in prod profile? Have you increased the logging level to get more details in logs?

Comment: I've seen this when the registry was unreachable from the app.  Is the registry's URL accessible from where the app is deployed?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou : although I haven't tested running locally, the same app works fine when deploying to kubernetes or openshift...

Comment: @JonRuddell: I can access the registry from my workstation and I'm using the same url in the app (following the JHipster instructions).
I suspected that to be the problem as well but found it extremely suspicious that there were no logs.

Comment: Where is your eureka registry running? Is it on PCF.? Have you binded this service to your app? Change the log level of the application to DEBUG and tail the logs using cf logs [App-Name] and see if any errors is thrown from Spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app needed to be correctly configured to use the registry as described in [JHipster Documentation: Doing Microservices](https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/#-going-to-production-with-cloud-foundry).

> In the bootstrap-prod.yml file, the spring.cloud.config.uri must point to http:///config/
>
> In the application-prod.yml file, the eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone must point to http:///eureka/

By default, the JHipster registry is authenticated with an admin:admin user, so the files above also need to be configured as described in [the Spring Cloud docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.RELEASE/#_security_2).

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: https://myconfig.mycompany.com
      username: user
      password: secret
```